# How do I change the value when I click on the right arrow?

Tags: jquery

When i click on the right arrow the next element of the array should be displayed in the input area?

```
$(function(){
    var room = ['1-visiting office', '2-', '3-'];       
    $('#text_holder').val(room[0]);

    $("#rightarrow").click(function(){      
        $('#text_holder').val(room[next]);      
    });
});
```

This is my html code

```
<input id="text_holder" name="text_holder"/>
<img src="dev/images/rightarrow.jpg" id="rightarrow" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Rocket's answer more than mine. But here's 1 more way if you find it useful.

```
$(function(){
    var room = ['1-visiting office', '2-', '3-'];       
    var counter = 0;
    $("#rightarrow").click(function(){      
        $('#text_holder').val(room[counter++]);     
    }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Array's don't have a `next` function or anything, you need to keep track of the counter yourself.

Here's a way to do that, using jQuery's `data` to store the counter on the button.

```
$(function(){
    var room = ['1-visiting office', '2-', '3-'];
    $('#text_holder').val(room[0]);

    $("#rightarrow").data('counter', 0).click(function(){
        var counter = $(this).data('counter')+1;
        $('#text_holder').val(room[counter]);
        $(this).data('counter', counter);
    });
});
```

If you want to loop around again after hitting the end, you can use the `%` (modulus) operator.

```
$(function(){
    var room = ['1-visiting office', '2-', '3-'];
    $('#text_holder').val(room[0]);

    $("#rightarrow").data('counter', 0).click(function(){
        var counter = ($(this).data('counter')+1) % room.length;
        $('#text_holder').val(room[counter]);
        $(this).data('counter', counter);
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8Fc9w/

Comment: You beat me to the punch, so I was putting together a jsFiddle of your code and you beat me to that punch with an edit. You did the wrap-around differently than I, so I went back to revise my jsFiddle and you added one of your own! RAAAAEEEEGGGGGEEE! :p +1

Comment: @Chris: Why do people forget that I am a ninja?

Comment: i have tried this but the next element in the array is not being displayed at the text area

Comment: @vamsi: Works fine in my demo, so I don't know what to tell ya.